# Assigning default attributes at a time

Tags: chef

Why in all OpsCode's cookbooks there is a

```
default[:netkernel][:version] = "4.1.1"
default[:netkernel][:install_url] = "http://apposite.netkernel.org/dist/1060-NetKernel-SE/1060-NetKernel-SE-4.1.1.jar"

default[:netkernel][:frontend][:port] = 8080

default[:netkernel][:backend][:address] = "localhost"
default[:netkernel][:backend][:port] = 1060

default[:netkernel][:user] = "netkernel"
default[:netkernel][:log_path] = "/var/log/netkernel"
```

instead of

```
default[:netkernel] = {
  :version => "4.1.1",
  :install_url => "http://apposite.netkernel.org/dist/1060-NetKernel-SE/1060-NetKernel-SE-4.1.1.jar",
  :frontend => {
    :port => 8080
  },
  :backend => {
    :address => "localhost"
  },
  :backend => {
    :port => 1060
  },
  :user => "netkernel",
  :log_path => "/var/log/netkernel"
}
```

Is this attributes definition equal to the first one?

Why first variant is prefered?

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed quite different and there for a reason, Mike's answer doesn't take into account how Chef works ( no offence meant ).

When looking a node attributes, you have to take into account the fact that a node has a run_list which defines the order in which cookbooks are run. Before any of the recipes are run, chef will iterate through the run_list and bring in cookbooks, each time merging in that cookbook's attributes.

In addition, each of the run_list element's dependent cookbooks will also be rolled in ( worth nothing dependent cookbooks are evaluated before the "parent" ).

So let's say you had two cookbooks "base_netkernel" and "specific_case_netkernel", you could have valid defaults set in base_netkernel and then only provide the attributes that are different / specific in specific_case_netkernel.

Hopefully that makes sense ;) If not, there's always the docs : https://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_attributes.html